# Getting location on service does not work

Tags: android, android-activity, service, location

I am using location service to listen location on background. But I have a problem with getting current location in service. It does not give me the proper result but 0,0 as coordinates. When I do the same operations on main activity, it gives the expected result. I think it is about context given to the gpstracker as a parameter but do not know what to do.

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

Context context;
Timer timer;
String latitude, longitude;
private String id;
GPSTracker gps;

public LocationService() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();  
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int isHere = isHere();
            Log.i("isHere", isHere + "");
            updateUserStatus(isHere);
        }

    }, 0, 200000);
    return START_STICKY;
}

private int isHere() {
    gps = new GPSTracker(context);
    if (!gps.canGetLocation()) {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        latitude = gps.getLatitude() + "";
        longitude = gps.getLongitude() + "";
        if (Math.abs(39.875303 - Double.parseDouble(latitude)) <= 0.001 || Math.abs(32.879980 - Double.parseDouble(longitude)) <= 0.001)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    return 0;

}

private void updateUserStatus(int isHere) {
    Call<Kisi> x = ManagerAll.getInstance().updateLocation(id, isHere);
    x.enqueue(new Callback<Kisi>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Kisi> call, Response<Kisi> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
                Log.i("durum", "başarılı");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Kisi> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

---

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

[Taken here](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)

Comment: pls post GPSTracker class

Comment: gps tracker class added as link

Comment: I think it is because your location received is null. In this case, try to move to outdoor spaces :)

Comment: no as I said, in the main activity it works fine. it is about service I think

Comment: onLocationChanged(Location location) can u pls pass to  location=location; // location and try

Comment: it doesnt work and as I said , there is no problem with gpstracker class, in my main method it works WELL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code.
this code work for me.

```
package com.yourpackage.tracker;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;

import com.orhanobut.hawk.Hawk;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import id.glite.transporter.GLiteApplication;
import id.glite.transporter.data.DataManager;
import id.glite.transporter.data.model.post.LocationUpdate;
import id.glite.transporter.util.rx.scheduler.SchedulerUtils;
import io.nlopez.smartlocation.SmartLocation;
import timber.log.Timber;

public class LocationTrackerService extends Service {
    // constant
    public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 3 * 60 * 1000; // 3 minutes

    // run on another Thread to avoid crash
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    // timer handling
    private Timer mTimer = null;

    private DataManager dataManager;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mContext = this;
        dataManager = GLiteApplication.get(getBaseContext()).getComponent().dataManager();
        // cancel if already existed
        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        } else {
            // recreate new
            mTimer = new Timer();
        }
        // schedule task
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
    }

    class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run on another thread
            // display toast
            mHandler.post(this::doTrackLocation);
        }

        private void doTrackLocation() {
            if (idTask != null) {
                SmartLocation.with(getBaseContext()).location()
                        .start(location -> {
                            List<Double> position = new ArrayList<>();
                            position.add(0, location.getLatitude());
                            position.add(1, location.getLongitude());

                        });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not get what it does exactly what I want is to get location each 5 mins

Comment: this example from me is get location for every 3 minutes. 
You just change this line 
 **public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 3 * 60 * 1000; // 3** minutes
to 
 **public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 5 * 60 * 1000; // 5 minutes**

Comment: it uses external libraries

Comment: Ok you're wellcom :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable the GPS on your phone and allowing the location permission as well.!